# Difference between MudBlazor's grid and container

Tags: blazor, mudblazor

I'm new to MudBlazor.

In bootstrap if I want to size content for multiple breakpoints I'd use the grid (`.container` and then `.row` and `.col-x`).

Mudblazor has a `MudGrid`, but it also has a `MudContainer` element.

In lots of sample code I noticed that people use it instead of a grid. So in bootstrap I would have to fiddle with `xs`, `md`, etc. for it to look good on all breakpoints, but in mudblazor people seem to use just the `MudContainer` with `MaxWidth`.

The docs aren't clear on this. When would you use the `MudGrid`, and when the `MudContainer`? Are they equivalent? Why the need for the container? Is the one easier to use than the other?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In MudBlazor, the `MudGrid` and `MudContainer` components serve different purposes, and they are not equivalent to one another. The `MudContainer` component is used to control the overall width and alignment of your content, while the `MudGrid` component is used to create responsive layouts with a 12-column grid system. Let's dive into the details of each component:

| Bootstrap | MudBlazor |
| --- | --- |
| `.container` | `MudContainer` |
| `.row` | `MudGrid` |
| `.col-xx` | `MudItem (with breakpoints)` |

### MudContainer

`MudContainer` is used to center your content and control its width. You have two options for sizing the content:

- Fluid: Set the `MaxWidth` of your container from `ExtraSmall` to `ExtraExtraLarge` according to your preference. This will allow your content to grow and shrink fluidly within the defined maximum width.
- Fixed: The container will "snap" to the closest breakpoint. This will create a more rigid layout that adapts to specific breakpoints.

### MudGrid

`MudGrid` is a responsive 12-point grid system, similar to the rows (`row`) and columns (`col-xx`) in Bootstrap. It is used for creating flexible layouts that adapt to different screen sizes. To control the layout at multiple breakpoints, you can use the `MudItem` component with different breakpoint properties (e.g., `xs`, `md`, etc.).

### When to use MudContainer and MudGrid

You should use `MudContainer` when you want to control the overall width and alignment of your content. On the other hand, use `MudGrid` when you need to create responsive layouts with multiple columns that adapt to different screen sizes.

In many cases, you will use both components together. For instance, you can wrap a `MudGrid` inside a `MudContainer` to create a responsive layout with a maximum width.

However, if you already have a container set up for your content body in your `MainLayout` template, you may not need to use `MudGrid` with a container, as nesting a container into another one may result in misalignment issues.

#### Animation Example

You can visualize the difference between MudBlazor's grid and container components in the animation below:

[image: Animation illustrating MudBlazor's grid and container components in various configurations.]

Code for the animation example:

```html
<MudContainer MaxWidth="MaxWidth.Small" Style="background-color: lightcoral; height: 50px;" Class="mt-2">
    MudContainer > MaxWidth="MaxWidth.Small"
</MudContainer>

<MudContainer Fixed="true" Style="background-color: darkseagreen; height: 50px;"  Class="mt-2">
    MudContainer > Fixed
</MudContainer>

<MudContainer Style="background-color:pink; height: 50px;"  Class="mt-2">
    MudGrid inside MudContainer
    <MudGrid Style="background-color: darkkhaki;">
        <MudItem xs="6">
            <MudPaper Class="d-flex align-center justify-center mud-width-full py-3">xs=6</MudPaper>
        </MudItem>
        <MudItem xs="6">
            <MudPaper Class="d-flex align-center justify-center mud-width-full py-3">xs=6</MudPaper>
        </MudItem>
    </MudGrid>
</MudContainer>

<br/><br/>MudGrid
<MudGrid Style="background-color: darkkhaki;">
    <MudItem xs="6">
        <MudPaper Class="d-flex align-center justify-center mud-width-full py-3">xs=6</MudPaper>
    </MudItem>
    <MudItem xs="6">
        <MudPaper Class="d-flex align-center justify-center mud-width-full py-3">xs=6</MudPaper>
    </MudItem>
</MudGrid>
```

Comment: Thanks. That sample code above is actually what confused me and led to this question. In bootstrap I'd use a container AND rows/cols to define a wide or narrow box. But in mudblazor you could do that with `<MudContainer MaxWidth="...">` OR `MudGrid`. The `MaxWidth` is like a short-cut, if you use it then you don't need to bother with the grid (in simple cases - in other cases you'd use both, as you explained). Does that make sense?

Comment: `MudGrid` is a 12-point grid system like the rows/cols in bootstrap. I think the confusion is that in the bootstap grid samples, you see each example of rows/cols inside a container but it does not mean you use a container each time. If you already setup a container for your content body as shown in `MainLayout` template, you only need to use `MudGrid` (rows/cols) alone. Also nesting a container into another one may result in misalignment issues.

Comment: @Ionix I have updated my answer. Hopefully it clears the confusion.